# NSTimeInterval to unix timestamp

Tags: ios, timestamp, nstimeinterval, core-motion

I'm getting  **CMDeviceMotion** objects from **CMMotionManager**. One of the properties of the CMDeviceMotion is timestamp, which is expressed as a NSTimeInterval (double). This allows for "sub millisecond" timestamp precision, according to documentation.

```
[motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:motionQueue withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error) { 
  NSLog(@"Sample: %d Timestamp: %f ",counter,  motion.timestamp);
}
```

Unfortunately, NSTimeInterval is calculated since last device boot, posing significant challenges to using it in its raw form.

Does anyone have a working code to convert this NSTimeInterval into a Unix like timestamp (UTC timezone)?

Thank you!

Comment: `NSTimeInterval` is usually relative to the reference date. Where do you get that this one is relative from the last device boot?

Comment: LOL at "sub millisecond." `NSTimeInterval` is a `double` with 53 bits of precision, giving a resolution of at least 1/2^52 * (time since 1/1/01). That currently comes out to about 80 nanoseconds. Not only didn't they gain *any* precision, as a minute with a handheld calculator would tell them, but now it's impossible to reliably calibrate the timestamps with anything else with even 10-millisecond precision. Furthermore, I suspect the measurements are taken at the sensor chip's leisure, whereas the timestamps reflect when the kernel got around to processing the data. What a mess.

Comment: Just look at the documentation, either in Xcode or the class reference - it clearly states (copied) "The timestamp is the amount of time in seconds since the device booted". Not since referenceTime.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had a similar problem when comparing magnetometer values with CoreMotion events. If you want to transform these NSTimeIntervals you just need to calculate the offset once:

```
// during initialisation

// Get NSTimeInterval of uptime i.e. the delta: now - bootTime
NSTimeInterval uptime = [NSProcessInfo processInfo].systemUptime;

// Now since 1970
NSTimeInterval nowTimeIntervalSince1970 = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];

// Voila our offset
self.offset = nowTimeIntervalSince1970 - uptime;
```

Comment: 2 questions. Can you subtract these time intervals directly? systemUpTime is not defined in the docs exactly as "boot time"m but rather "The amount of time the system has been awake since the last time it was restarted.". Can there be gaps when the system is not "awake" (e.g. asleep etc.) ???

Answer (score 2):

I imagine it is supposed to be used as a relative measure to allow you to sequence motion events correctly, so they went for as lightweight an implementation as possible.

I can't think why you'd need the actual date and time of a motion event as they are all dealt with pretty much straight away. But if you really wanted to, you'd have to get the timestamp of one event, use that with the current date to work out the base date, and then use your base date to derive the actual time of subsequent events.

Comment: I was afraid as such. I was hoping to plot the motion events later, allowing the users to compare motion events (Actigraphy app).  This means a lot more math on my part :(

Comment: Not too much. NSDate's dateByAddingTimeInterval will do most of it for you.