# ARKit: What does the ARFrame.timestamp represent?

Tags: ios, timestamp, unix-timestamp, arkit

In ARKit, [ARFrame.timestamp](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arframe/2867973-timestamp) is a `TimeInterval` with values such

```
185726.884258291
185726.91759425
185726.950930291
...
```

I'd like to get the unix timestamp from these values, but they don't look familiar.  What do these numbers represent?

Comment: If you're looking for a UNIX timestamp than here is the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7583042/3641812

Comment: @ricardopereira Are you saying that it is some sort of offset from the CPU start time?  If you want to add an answer with details, I'll award you the points if it looks good.

Answer (score 2):

These numbers represent uptime at the moment the frame has been captured, see it yourself by calling

```
NSTimeInterval systemUptime = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] systemUptime];
```

[Methods and thoughts about converting it to a Unix Timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7576017/nstimeinterval-to-unix-timestamp).